# What is the FileInput node Message Id?

Tags: messagebroker

What is the message identifier in a FileInput node? Or.. is there any way to get a unique identifier after a file is read?

When we use the MQInput node the MQMD is used to get the MsgId, but here I don't know how to get this property, if there is one. I have tried adding a MQ Header next to the InputFile node to add a message Id (MsgId = MQMI_NONE), but always get 0000..., in other words.. it does not generate a new MsgId.

Any help is very appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I did it using the UUIDASCHAR function in a Compute Node:

```
DECLARE MsgId CHAR; 
SET MsgId = UUIDASCHAR;
```

It is not a FileInput specific property, but it works for the purpose of creating a unique identifier to the message flow.